# ExtJS 4, store loading, but store.first() method returning undefined

Tags: load, extjs4, store

I'm creating and loading a store just fine.  However, when I attempt to retrieve a record from the first model instance, using the first() method, it fails.

Here's the code:

```
     var getCaseId = function(){
            var csId;    
            //form url
            var getCaseIdStore = Ext.create('Roa.store.district.Requests', {

            model: 'Roa.model.district.Requests',
            proxy: {
                    type: 'ajax',
                    url : 'http://localhost:8080/roa/MongoDataService/requests?etc',
                    method: 'GET',

                    reader: {
                            type: 'json',
                            root: 'requests'
                    }   
            },  
            autoLoad: true
    });//end create store

                    console.log('request store created');

    getCaseIdStore.load({
    scope: this,
    callback: function(records,operation,success){

            if(success){

                    //var req = getCaseIdStore.first();
                    //var csId = req.get('caseId');
                    //console.log('csId==>'+csId);

                   //return csId;  

            }//end if

    }//end callback

    });//end store load


    var req = getCaseIdStore.first();

    if (req != undefined){
    csId = req.get('caseId');

    console.log('return csId==>'+csId);

     return csId;    
     }               
    else{           
    console.log('your attempt failed');
    }               

    };//end function
```

Please advise good folks.

-TU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading process is asynchronous. You can't just call it and then try to get the first record - move your .first() call into store loading callback as you have it in commented out lines. These lines should work just fine.

Comment: .first() inside callback is fine.

Comment: Yes it works.  However, I'm having some difficulty understanding how to get the csId value from the callback to be returned by the encompassing function--getCaseId().

Comment: You can't... You're trying to think about encompassing function as a synchronous function, however you will get control back from that function right after you initiated load operation. You need to re-design a bit code that calls this function to not rely on the result of it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

A huge shot in the dark, but if your load scope is 'this' it might not have getCaseIdStore? Perhaps just replace getCaseIdStore within the callback to 'this'?

Comment: I answered assuming the commented lines are the ones failing (within the load). If the non-commented line is the one failing then see sha's reply.

Comment: No, the commented code works.   I'm just striving to understand how to access the return value -- csId -- outside of the store.load() method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the  getCaseIdStore.isLoading( ) method to check when the store finished the load opertation.  then you can proceed with your .first() call.